# Number problems in two columns

Tags: numbering, two-column

I am creating worksheets and I would like to have multiple rows with 2 columns.  I would like the numbering to go horizontally, i.e.,

```
1. math problem              2. math problem
3. math problem              4. math problem
5. math problem              6. math problem
7. math problem              8. math problem
```

I am working in the article class (although I need this for the exam class as well) and have been playing around with array/tabular, minipage, and creating my own commands... I am still new at this, thank you for your patience.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,graphicx,mathtools,flexisym, array, multirow, tabularx, enumitem, multicol}

\newlist{mparts}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[mparts]{label*=(\arabic*)}
\newcommand{\mpart}{\item}

\SetEnumitemKey{twocol}{
  before=\raggedcolumns\begin{multicols}{2},
  after=\end{multicols}}

\begin{document}
\subsection{Finding Limits Analytically}
When a function is defined and continuous at a value $x=a$, how can $\lim 
\limits_{x\to a} f(x)$ be found analytically?
\vspace{0.5in}
\begin{mparts}[twocol]
    \mpart $\lim \limits_{x\to 3} \dfrac{1}{2}x^2-2x+3$
    \mpart $\lim \limits_{x\to 3} \dfrac{5x+2}{2x-3}$
    \mpart $\lim \limits_{x\to 2^{-}} \dfrac{\sqrt{x+2}-1}{x+1}$
    \mpart $\lim \limits_{\theta \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \sin{2\theta}$
\end{mparts}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the numbering goes vertically down as I add more problems.  While this is largely cosmetic, I'd like to know how to change it to look they way I'd prefer it to look.

I also don't know how to insert an image here.  But the format looks generally like this:

```
1. math problem          3. math problem
2. math problem          4. math problem
```

Many thanks!

Comment: `\usepackage{tasks}` and `\begin{tasks}(2) \task...\end{tasks}` instead of the `mpart`, i.e. `\task` is what `\mpart` does (effectively), but in an horizontal sweep, `(2)` means '2 columns' here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of

```
   \usepackage{tasks}
    \NewTasks[style=enumerate]{myitemize}[\item](2)

    %you can edit the style to "itemize" for bullets
    %you can change the number from '2' to any number of columns you would like

        \begin{document}

        \begin{myitemize}
          \item item 1
          \item item 2
          \item item 3
          \item item 4
        \end{myitemize}

        \end{document}
```