# Two enumerate commands, one counter (this is not just "resuming a list")

Tags: enumerate, columns

I am creating a document where I use numbered lists.  I have two environments for my lists: the regular enumerate command (one column) and a personalized, two column enumerate command.  I have no idea what the correct vocabulary is for this, very sorry, still new to Latex.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,graphicx,mathtools,flexisym,tasks,enumitem,multicol,mdframed,tabularx}

%my itemized lists in two columns
\NewTasks[style=enumerate]{myitemize}[\item](2)

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate} % this should be numbered 1, 2
\item this is in one column
\item because this problem is worked horizontally
\end{enumerate}

\begin{myitemize} % this should be numbered 3, 4 in the first row and 5, 6 in the second row, etc.
\item but these problems
\item are in two columns
\item because they are better
\item when worked vertically
\end{myitemize}

\begin{enumerate} % this should be numbered 8, 9
\item but then you have to do some writing
\item which happens horizontally
\item so we are back to one column
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I would like to continue the number system despite the change in format.  So we should see each item numbered consecutively 1-9.  What is happening, as I'm sure you know, is that the count resets each time.  I have tried to use [resume] and manually change the counters, but this is not great since I frequently go back and add items to my list willy-nilly.  Note: [resume] works GREAT for both the enumerate and myitemize commands!  But they don't work together.

I feel like this is close: [Resuming a list started within a minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21596/resuming-a-list-started-within-a-minipage) but not quite what I need since I've defined my own list making thing.  I have tried using [resume*, start=5] but it doesn't seem to be working for my two column command.  I am also exploring this: [How to resume list numbering (enumerated lists) with multicols environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91234/how-to-resume-list-numbering-enumerated-lists-with-multicols-environments) but then it is not numbering the way that I want it to be numbered (that is, it is counting down the column and not across the rows which is a problem I already panic-submitted [Number problems in two columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389086/number-problems-in-two-columns)).

Thank you in advance, and I am happy to clarify if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\NewTasks` command is very flexible:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsfonts, amssymb, graphicx, flexisym, tasks, enumitem, multicol, mdframed, tabularx}

%my itemized lists in two columns by default
\NewTasks[style=enumerate]{myitemize}[\item](2)

\begin{document}

\begin{myitemize}(1)
  \item this is in one column
  \item because this problem is worked horizontally
\end{myitemize}

\begin{myitemize}[resume]%
  \item but these problems
  \item are in two columns
  \item because they are better
  \item when worked vertically
\end{myitemize}

\begin{myitemize}[resume](1)%
  \item but then you have to do some writing
  \item which happens horizontally
  \item so we are back to one column
\end{myitemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]